# JSON Javascript highlighting in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

Does anybody know how to get VS 2010 to use the same highlighting for a file called .JSON as it uses for a JavaScript file? Just working on a client site and they've named all their JSON template files as .JSON, with the result that I just get a plain old text editor when I open it in Visual Studio. Any suggestions? I'm sure there must be an option somewhere that would do it but I can't find it so far...

Comment: I've created a suggestion on the VS user voice site. Please vote for it: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4034793

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension

End your extension 'json' and select 'Script Editor' and click 'add'.

Re-open any json documents for it to take affect.

Comment: this will give you a bit of syntax coloring but in that raw json is not valid javascript from the editor's perspective you lose any formatting support and the page is full of green squigglies. What is needed is a JSON specific editor.

Comment: @SkySanders How is raw JSON not valid Javascript?

Comment: a file *just* holding:

    {
        a: 72,
        b: "bugs bunny"
    }

is valid json but not valid javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [Text Highlighter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6706b602-6f10-4fd1-8e14-75840f855569) (extention for Visual Studio 2010), which offers syntax highlighting for the following text formats:

- **.json (also offer syntax validation)**
- .bat
- .cmd
- .ini
- .txt
- .log

Comment: +1; also available as an [extension for Visual Studio 2012](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd129629-a1a1-417c-ac80-c9ac7a67b968).

Answer (score 2):

Great news!

In  **CTP2 of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2** that was added a [**New JSON project item and editor**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx)

[image]