# How can I get Visual Studio to source highlight .json source code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2010, ide

How can I get VS to source highlight .json source code?  I'd also like to have it have some of the same key-bindings that normal JavaScript enjoys.  In a way all I'd really need/want is a way to have Visual Studio recognize a .json file as a .js file (I think).  Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Javascript highlighting in Visual Studio 2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034082/json-javascript-highlighting-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Visual Studio Extension TextHighlighter:

VS 2010: [TextHighlighterExtension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6706b602-6f10-4fd1-8e14-75840f855569)
VS 2012: [TextHighlighterExtension12](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fd129629-a1a1-417c-ac80-c9ac7a67b968)

Comment: This could work, I guess, I'm no longer on Windows using VS to check.  I need some way to transfer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Great news!

In  **CTP2 of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2** that was added a [**New JSON project item and editor**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/25/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx)

One more post [New JSON editor features in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 CTP2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/28/new-json-editor-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2-ctp2.aspx)

[image: JSON editor in Visual Studio supports data types]

[image: JSON editor in VS2013 adds warnings to Error List]

[image: JSON editor in VS2013 Update 2 CTP2]

Answer (score 2):

Navigate starting at the top menu bar,

TOOLS --> Options --> Text Editor --> File Extensions

Here you can add `json` as an entry, however, the `Script Editor` will not work at all, you can use `Visual C++` editor experience which will provide very basic highlighting until Microsoft can get with the program and add some basic JSON support.

Answer (score 0):

Into the menus
Tools .. Options .. Text Editor .. File Extensions

Add the JSON extension and choose to use the Script Editor

Comment: This didn't seem to work.  I have a .json file filled with plain simple json.  It doesn't highlight the strings or comments.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a json file isn't valid javascript. (A file containing just a javascript literals without an assignment is invalid.) So while it will highlight, Visual Studio will be convinced your file's wrong, and (personally) I find that more annoying than the lack of highlighting.

There is this project: http://jsonviewer.codeplex.com/ but that seems old and not currently maintained. (Also it seems like it's just a visualizer, not a syntax highlighting plugin.)

I'm currently look for a good plugin for this, or possibly writing one.